# Can a Chrome app open a file in explorer?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

When you download a file with Chrome you can click `Show in folder` from the downloads page. Chrome will then open whatever file manager is standard for your OS.

Can a Chrome app do the same? Say you make a download manager of some kind, is it then possible to show a list of your downloads and have the extension open the file in the default file manager?

The app in question uses the `fileSystem` API so the downloaded files could be anywhere, not just in the default download folder.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

Comment: @JoshLee Irrelevant: this is an extension API, not an App API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I'm afraid the answer is "not without an additional Native Host module".

The `fileSystem` API does not provide any tools to open files/folders with native OS programs (e.g. file manager). Yes, you can request access to any location in the filesystem, but you can't force stuff to "run" (in the most general sense) once you get it.

At most, you can have a [Native Host module](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging) that will call the OS file manager. Considering that's impossible on Chrome OS, which is currently the only target that's not deprecated for Apps, the answer leans more towards a simple "No".